# Why would a simulation nodes setup stop simulating after a certain length of time?

Tags: geometry-nodes, fluid-simulation, simulation-nodes

I've got a fluid sim running in simulation nodes (based on Bad Normals' [setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_vnAz0Yo8w)). I need it to work for quite a long time (around 5000 frames), but I've noticed it currently stops moving the particles at frame 1567. This is just the simulation nodes part of the geonodes setup - there are other nodes making the particles spin, and they keep spinning past this point.

The frame range currently runs from 1 to 3215. There's no simulation range set in Scene > Simulation. It feels like I'm missing something obvious :S

(Blender 4.0.2, RTX 4090, 128GB RAM)

Comment: Did you try baking your simulation zone ? Otherwise, I think your cache may be full.

Comment: I've baked it, yes - does the cache have a maximum size though?

Comment: I'm not sure. You'll greatly increasing your chances of getting useful answers by uploading your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ and adding some screenshots to your post.

Comment: @Nickh129: as Lutzi commented, and to say it more directly: how shall we help you without seeing any of your technical settings you made?

Comment: Fair questions, and thanks for your help. I can't really share the blend file as it's a project for someone else, but I think this is probably a weird cache issue. I'll try deleting and remaking the cache and see if that fixes things - just wanted to see if there was something obvious I was doing wrong

Comment: @Nickh129 Consider deleting all privacy-sensitive content (objects, textures, images, ...) and upload it. Be careful though.